# Router resolves LAN DNS names to WAN IPs

Tags: router, dns, lan, wan

I have a router on a LAN with 4 computers. One computer is a server with a static IP; the others are dynamic IP. All 4 DNS names resolve to an IP that is outside my LAN (i.e. a 208.* address instad of a 192.* address) and has a ping response time to match it (50-60ms instead of <1).

The only DNS-related option I see in the router configuration is "Enable DNS Relay". When I disable that, all LAN systems resolve correctly but Internet/WAN address cease to resolve at all.

What would cause a router to behave in such a manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it.

I had a domain name pointing at my IP address, and let the domain expire. However, I forgot that the router was configured with that domain name. I removed it and reset the device, but it still happened.

Then, on each of my client machines, I ran:

- ipconfig /flushdns
- ipconfig /release /renew

and it spontaneously started resolving correctly. Apparently the clients' FQDN (i.e. hostname.domain.com) was persisting in the DNS cache?

Comment: This is a question, not an answer. It should be added to the original question as an edit or a comment.

Comment: @Xavierjax - no, it's the answer to his question.  If you solve it yourself, posting your solution as an answer is correct.